# Dynamically Display Remotely Populated Dropdown in Vue.JS

Tags: javascript, html, rest, vue.js, dropdown

Please find attached the UI I'm trying to implement for clearer context.
[image]

I'm able to implement adding and removing the drop-down list and text-box dynamically with the + and - buttons but the problem is...selecting an item from one drop-down also changes the value of other drop-down. How can I prevent this and also get the data required in each line. i.e the stock code and unit.

Below are some relevant code snippets.

```
    <template>
<div>
<div v-for="(stock, index) in stocks" :key="index" class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<select class="form-control" v-model="listofStocks">
<option v-for="stk in stocklist" v-bind:value="stk.symbol">
{{stk.name}}
</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
<input v-model="stock.units" type="number" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">

<button v-if="index +1 === stocks.length" @@click="addLine"  class="btn btn-link button"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
<button @@click="removeLine(index)" class="btn btn-link button"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</template>
```

SCRIPT

```
return Vue.component('reciept', {
template: '#reciept_tpl',
props: {

},
data: function () {
return {
listofStocks: [],
stocklist: null,
stocks: [],
}
},
computed: {
modalId: function () {
return 'reciept-modal-' + this.compId
}
},
watch: {
stocks() {
this.blockRemoval = this.stocks.length <= 1
}
},
methods: {        
  getStockPrices: function () {
$.LoadingOverlay("show")
var url = 'url';
$.get(url).done((resp) => {
    this.stocklist = resp.data;
    if (resp.data.length == 0) {
        //Display error
    }
}).fail(error => {
    utils.displayAlert(error.responseJSON.message).then(() => {})
});

},
addLine() {
let checkEmptyLines = this.stocks.filter(stock => stock.number === null)
if (checkEmptyLines.length >= 1 && this.stocks.length > 0) {
return
}
this.stocks.push({
stockCode: null,
units: null,
})
},

removeLine(lineId) {
if (!this.blockRemoval) {
this.stocks.splice(lineId, 1)
}
}

},
beforeMount: function () {
this.compId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)
},
mounted: function () {
this.getStockPrices();
this.addLine();
}
});
})(jQuery)
```

Please note that the data in the drop-down list is remotely populated from a REST endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

That the issue is is that you're binding the same parameter to the multiple select fields. So, when one select field is changed, it triggers others to change.

What you have to do is re-organize your component.

1. Extract the select field and text input to a separate component. (component can be named something like this: 'stock-list'.
2. Create an array with the list of stocks and number of units as parameters. Something like this:

```js
stockList: [{stockCode: "BUACEM", units: 0}]
```

3. Mount the component and add a v-for attribute to the stockList variable. something like this:

   ```html
   <stock-list v-for="stock in stockList" :key="stock.stockCode"></stock-list>
   ```

This should solve the issue.

You can then add to the stockList array when handling the click event for the plus button while you remove from it using the minus button.

Hope that suffices.